# Create image from RGB list with Pillow and Python 3

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, stringio

I have a list of RGB data:

```
cdata=[R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2,..., Rn, Gn, Bn]
```

where each value is comprised between 0 to 255.

I am trying to rebuild this array as an image using Pillow 5.0.0.
Under Python 2, I was able to convert the list of values into a byte string this way:

```
        cdata2 = []
        gidx = len(cdata)//3
        bidx = len(cdata)//3*2
        for i in range(len(cdata)//3):
            cdata2.append(cdata[i])
            cdata2.append(cdata[i+gidx])
            cdata2.append(cdata[i+bidx])

        data = ""
        for c in cdata2:
            data += chr(c)

        im = Image.frombytes("RGB", (420, 560), data)
```

and then reincode 'im' in base64 and display it as a PNG in an HTML template.

Unfortunately this does not work in Python 3, I am having errors like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 42099-42101: character maps to <undefined>
```

Furthermore, Pillow 5 documentation now suggests using

```
im = Image.open(StringIO(data))
```

but cannot make it work with my string built above. Is there any more clever way to do this? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: In Python 3, plain strings are for (Unicode) text, don't try to use them for binary data. Instead, you should be using `bytearray`, or possibly `bytes` objects. Is Numpy an option for you? How come your RGB values range from 0-254 instead of 0-255?

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring. Yes, they are up to 255 indeed, will correct this. I can use Numpy. How would you encode the RGB channel data then to use it with Pillow please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example using `frombytes`. This is just using pure Python, no Numpy. If you're using Numpy to create the RGB values then you can use the `Image.fromarray` method to convert the Numpy data into a PIL Image.

The important step here is to convert the list of RGB values into a `bytes` object, which is easily done by passing it to the `bytes` constructor.

```
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb
from PIL import Image

# Make some RGB values. 
# Cycle through hue vertically & saturation horizontally
colors = []
for hue in range(360):
    for sat in range(100):
        # Convert color from HSV to RGB
        rgb = hsv_to_rgb(hue/360, sat/100, 1)
        rgb = [int(0.5 + 255*u) for u in rgb]
        colors.extend(rgb)

# Convert list to bytes
colors = bytes(colors)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (100, 360), colors)
img.show()
img.save('hues.png')
```

**output**

[image: hue & saturation demo image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Image.frombytes`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes). `Image.open` is intended for opening encoded images (like jpg or png), not raw RGB data.

---

Constructing the required byte data is trivial with the `bytes` constructor:

```
img_bytes = bytes([R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2,..., Rn, Gn, Bn])
```

And then we can create an Image like so:

```
im = Image.frombytes("RGB", (width, height), img_bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have nice Python2 and Python3 compatible code you can use struct or array module:

```
# Works from Python 2.5 (maybe earlier) to Python 3.x
import struct
cdata = [...]
bindata = struct.pack("<%dB" % len(cdata), *cdata)
# And then use PIL's Image.frombytes() to construct the Image() from bindata
```

Or:

```
import array
cdata = [...]
a = array.array("B", cdata)
bindata = a.tostring()
# And then use PIL's Image.frombytes() to construct the Image() from bindata
# This should be faster than struct, but I didn't test it for speed
```